# font awesome icon not working in windows server but working in linux server

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, fonts, icons

I use font awesome icon in a bootstrap template.
but  font awesome icon are not working in widows server .
but working properly in linux server.
windows server url : http://bazaarhat.webinfotech.in/
linux server url : http://www.webinfotechin.com/bazaarhat/
what is the solution.

Comment: can you show your code that how you have loaded the font-awesome

Comment: in Html page :  <link href="css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">    and in css page  :  @font-face
{
/*url(../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.svg)*/
  font-family:'FontAwesome';
  src:url('../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.eot');
  src:url('../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
      url('../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
      url('../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
      url('../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.svg#FontAwesome') format('svg');
  font-weight:normal;
  font-style:normal
}  in fonts folder the fonts are placed .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've got smth wrong with your fontawesome.css loading. It seems to be in a wrong place.
If your add a maxcdn fontawesome link to your `<head>`, everything works as expected.

Insert this in `<head>`:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
```